# LLDB expression command with print not showing anything in console when attached on other process

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, lldb

As a developer I want to be able to use the `expression print(..)` LLDB command.
In my app I have NotificationServiceExtension process that is handling the presentation of push notifications. I am attaching LLDB to NotificationService process using XCode > Debug.

The problem is that when setting a breakpoint on NotificationService process and try to use the following command I am getting:

```swift
(lldb) expr print("foo")
() $R12 = {}
```

and when I am executing from my app process:

```swift
(lldb) expr print("foo")
foo
() $R0 = {}
```

Am I missing something? Because of this I am unable to use this custom command for printing apns payload.

```swift
command regex poj 's/(.+)/expr print(NSString(string: String(data: try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: %1, options: [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys]), encoding: .utf8)!))/'
```

Answer (score 1):

The expression evaluator runs the code you give it "as if it had been compiled in your application at the stop point."  So when you run:

```
(lldb) expr print("something\n")
```

that is going to go to the stdout of your program, just as it would in code.  If you are attaching to a program, stdout is already set to somewhere, though for a NotificationService, stdout may very well be /dev/null.

But I don't see why you need to print this to the debuggee's stdout.  If you ran the expression:

```
(lldb) expr NSString(string: String(data: try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: %1, options: [.prettyPrinted, .sortedKeys]), encoding: .utf8)!)
```

The result will be that string, and it will print the contents to the debug console so you can see it.  It will also get captured in a "result" variable (that's the $R0 in the expr return, which you can use to print the string to the debug console again using:

```
(lldb) expr $R0
```

Comment: The reason I want to use print() is because if I don't the output contains '\n' chars and is not so readable compared to using print.

Comment: You could write a little Python based lldb command that runs the expression, takes the resultant string and prints the bits between the newlines to the command result piece by piece.

Comment: When we show you a string, we show you the string as written in the programming language, since that's what you wrote in your code.  But it would be useful to have something like a `--render` mode for the printing that does some minimal rendering (\n's and \t's mostly...)  Just calling `print` isn't a good general solution  since some random string might have pieces that look like variable substitution, which will cause the print to fail.